# Flutter - AWS AmplifyStorageS3 and AmplifyDataStore Plugins not added successfully

Tags: android, flutter, storage, aws-amplify, datastore

I am trying to configure the AWS Amplify Plugins AmplifyDataStore and AmplifyStorageS3 for Flutter.

I am receiving the following error:

```
I/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito( 1242): Added Auth plugin
I/amplify:flutter:api( 1242): Added API plugin
I/flutter ( 1242): Amplify plugin was not added
E/flutter ( 1242): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: AmplifyException(message: Amplify plugin AmplifyDataStore was not added successfully., recoverySuggestion: We currently don't have a recovery suggestion for this exception., underlyingException: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method configureModelProvider on channel com.amazonaws.amplify/datastore))
E/flutter ( 1242): #0      AmplifyClass.addPlugin (package:amplify_flutter/amplify.dart:102:9)
E/flutter ( 1242): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1242):
I/flutter ( 1242): Amplify plugin was not added
E/flutter ( 1242): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: AmplifyException(message: Amplify plugin AmplifyStorageS3 was not added successfully., recoverySuggestion: We currently don't have a recovery suggestion for this exception., underlyingException: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method addPlugin on channel com.amazonaws.amplify/storage_s3))
E/flutter ( 1242): #0      AmplifyClass.addPlugin (package:amplify_flutter/amplify.dart:102:9)
E/flutter ( 1242): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1242):
E/flutter ( 1242): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method configure on channel com.amazonaws.amplify/amplify)
E/flutter ( 1242): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 1242): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1242): #1      AmplifyClass.configure (package:amplify_flutter/amplify.dart:175:17)
E/flutter ( 1242): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1242): #2      _MyAppState._configureAmplify (package:insighteur_app/main.dart:46:7)
E/flutter ( 1242): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1242):
```

Below is the screenshot of the class in main.dart file:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _amplifyConfigured = false;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureAmplify();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _amplifyConfigured ? Text('Check') : HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _configureAmplify() async {
    // Add the following lines to your app initialization to add the DataStore plugin
    Amplify.addPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito());

    Amplify.addPlugin(AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: ModelProvider.instance));
    Amplify.addPlugin(AmplifyAPI());
    Amplify.addPlugin(AmplifyStorageS3());

    try {
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
      setState(() {
        _amplifyConfigured = true;
      });
    } on AmplifyAlreadyConfiguredException {
      print(
          "Tried to reconfigure Amplify; this can occur when your app restarts on Android.");
    }
  }
}
```

My amplifyconfiguration.dart file is shown below:

```
const amplifyconfig = ''' {
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "auth": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
                "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
                "Version": "0.1.0",
                "IdentityManager": {
                    "Default": {}
                },
                "CredentialsProvider": {
                    "CognitoIdentity": {
                        "Default": {
                            "PoolId": "us-west-2:fafb1966-fc0b-41e0-92e5-3124d5a8d27a",
                            "Region": "us-west-2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "CognitoUserPool": {
                    "Default": {
                        "PoolId": "us-west-2_aH29w4X7B",
                        "AppClientId": "17c0b97ouv640bcp87m9v8pgtp",
                        "Region": "us-west-2"
                    }
                },
                "Auth": {
                    "Default": {
                        "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH"
                    }
                },
                "S3TransferUtility": {
                    "Default": {
                        "Bucket": "insighteur3f5d08559c174463a5a2aa8681fc3dbe174435-dev",
                        "Region": "us-west-2"
                    }
                },
                "AppSync": {
                    "Default": {
                        "ApiUrl": "https://3w7mmufy5rdrlacj2qeg27zd7q.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
                        "Region": "us-west-2",
                        "AuthMode": "API_KEY",
                        "ApiKey": "da2-u3xpqm5wvfbntmqor5cglgcatq",
                        "ClientDatabasePrefix": "insighteur_API_KEY"
                    },
                    "insighteur_AWS_IAM": {
                        "ApiUrl": "https://3w7mmufy5rdrlacj2qeg27zd7q.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
                        "Region": "us-west-2",
                        "AuthMode": "AWS_IAM",
                        "ClientDatabasePrefix": "insighteur_AWS_IAM"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "storage": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsS3StoragePlugin": {
                "bucket": "insighteur3f5d08559c174463a5a2aa8681fc3dbe174435-dev",
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "defaultAccessLevel": "guest"
            }
        }
    },
    "api": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsAPIPlugin": {
                "insighteur": {
                    "endpointType": "GraphQL",
                    "endpoint": "https://3w7mmufy5rdrlacj2qeg27zd7q.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
                    "region": "us-west-2",
                    "authorizationType": "API_KEY",
                    "apiKey": "da2-u3xpqm5wvfbntmqor5cglgcatq"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}''';
```

pubspec.yaml file dependencies are listed below:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_color: any
  flutter_color_models: ^1.2.1

  amplify_flutter: '<1.0.0'
  amplify_auth_cognito: '<1.0.0'
  amplify_analytics_pinpoint: '<1.0.0'
  amplify_storage_s3: '<1.0.0'
  #file_picker: ^3.0.1
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1
  amplify_datastore: '<1.0.0'
  intl: ^0.15.7
  amplify_api: '<1.0.0'

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I have tried shutting down the app, `flutter clean`, `flutter upgrade`(using version 2.14.0), restarting Android mobile AVD...

Comment: EDIT - The problem got solved by cloning a new workspace again.

Comment: Which Workspace? Flutter or Amplify pull ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. I cloned my git workspace again.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you get a `Plugin not added exception`, this is usually because you are performing a `hot-reload` operation `AFTER` adding the plugin to your app. You need to `STOP` the app completely and then `RUN` it again. This was the issue for me

Comment: right. that was it!

Answer (score 0):

1. `add amplify add storage` if successful then
2. `amplify push`
3. Upon completion, amplifyconfiguration.dart will be updated to reference a newly provisioned S3 bucket.
4. Add the following dependency to your app‘s pubspec.yaml along with others you added above in Prerequisites:

   dependencies:
   flutter:
   sdk: flutter
   amplify_storage_s3: '<1.0.0'

   ## reminder: amplify_auth_cognito should also be installed
5. import this to your project :

   // // main.dart
   // reminder: import 'package:amplify_auth_cognito/amplify_auth_cognito.dart';
   import 'package:amplify_storage_s3/amplify_storage_s3.dart';
6. Initialize Amplify Storage

   // Add this line, to include Auth and Storage plugins.
   `Amplify.addPlugins([AmplifyAuthCognito(), AmplifyStorageS3()]);`
7. Uploading data to your bucket

   ```
   void uploadFile() async {
     // use a file selection mechanism of your choice
     File file = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.image);
     final key = new DateTime.now().toString();
     UploadFileResult result = await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
       key: key,
       local: file
     );
   }
   ```

Here is amplify doc https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/flutter#uploading-data-to-your-bucket

Comment: I have previously completed steps #1 - #6.  I have also imported `amplify_auth_cognito.dart`, `amplify_datastore_plugin_interface.dart`, `amplify_datastore.dart`, `amplify_storage_s3.dart`.  The code seems to compile but there are errors with the way Plugins are added. AmplifyAuthCognito() and AmplifyAPI() seems to be added fine, only AmplifyDataStore() and AmplifyStorageS3() not added correctly.